Linked List Node structure isn't making sense C++
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class IntNode {
public:
   IntNode(int dataInit = 0, IntNode* nextLoc = nullptr);
   void InsertAfter(IntNode* nodeLoc);
   IntNode* GetNext();
   void PrintNodeData();
private:
   int dataVal;
   IntNode* nextNodePtr;
};

// Constructor
IntNode::IntNode(int dataInit, IntNode* nextLoc) {
   this->dataVal = dataInit;
   this->nextNodePtr = nextLoc;
}

/* Insert node after this node.
 * Before: this -- next
 * After:  this -- node -- next
 */
void IntNode::InsertAfter(IntNode* nodeLoc) {
   IntNode* tmpNext = nullptr;
   
   tmpNext = this->nextNodePtr;    // Remember next
   this->nextNodePtr = nodeLoc;    // this -- node -- ?
   nodeLoc->nextNodePtr = tmpNext; // this -- node -- next
}

// Print dataVal
void IntNode::PrintNodeData() {
   cout << this->dataVal << endl;
}

// Grab location pointed by nextNodePtr
IntNode* IntNode::GetNext() {
   return this->nextNodePtr;
}

int main() {
   IntNode* headObj  = nullptr; // Create IntNode pointers
   IntNode* nodeObj1 = nullptr;
   IntNode* nodeObj2 = nullptr;
   IntNode* nodeObj3 = nullptr;
   IntNode* currObj  = nullptr;
   
   // Front of nodes list
   headObj = new IntNode(-1);
   
   // Insert nodes
   nodeObj1 = new IntNode(555);
   headObj->InsertAfter(nodeObj1);
   
   nodeObj2 = new IntNode(999);
   nodeObj1->InsertAfter(nodeObj2);
   
   nodeObj3 = new IntNode(777);
   nodeObj2->InsertAfter(nodeObj3);
   
   // Print linked list
   currObj = headObj;
   while (currObj != nullptr) {
      currObj->PrintNodeData();
      currObj = currObj->GetNext();
   }
   
   return 0;
}

I'm having issues deciphering exactly what this code is saying and how it's supposed to work. My current understanding of C++ syntax doesn't seem to be correct. The code above produces a linked list, with the pointer values of the last node pointing to the memory block that contains the value of the next node.
Firstly, the declaration of the Node itself doesn't make any sense and is unusual compared to a standard variable declaration like
int number;

To my understanding, the Nodes declared in int main () are being defined by a default constructor. Distinct instances of dataVal and nextNodePtr are initialized whenever the default constructor is called. dataVal is initialized to 0, and nextNodePtr is initialized to null.
void IntNode::InsertAfter(IntNode* nodeLoc) {
   IntNode* tmpNext = nullptr;
   
   tmpNext = this->nextNodePtr;    // Remember next
   this->nextNodePtr = nodeLoc;    // this -- node -- ?
   nodeLoc->nextNodePtr = tmpNext; // this -- node -- next

The insertion code doesn't make any sense to me. I don't know how exactly I'm supposed to be interpreting this
From what I'm seeing, this is a member function that creates a tmpNext variable and assigns it with null. I fail to see the point of this-> in this context. The InsertAfter function is taking the specific node object, creating a tmpNext Node every time the function is called and assigning it a null value. The tmpNext is then assigned the value of nextNodePtr for the specific Node object put into the function which should be null.
If the headObj is inserted into the function, it's nullptr value for nextNodePtr is assigned with headObj. So headObj is pointing to itself? I also don't know how to read the next line.

IntNode* headObj = nullptr; defines a variable named headObj. It is of the type IntNode*, i.e. it's a pointer to an IntNode object but is not an IntObject in itself. And lastly headObj is initialized with nullptr, i.e. the pointer is a null-pointer. This is not that different from int* intptr = nullptr;. Or indeed int intval = 0;.

As a way to better understanding what the code actually does (and assuming you din't write this yourself, and I really recommend you try to implement a list yourself to understand it better), please draw it. Use a debugger to step through the code line by line, while drawing what it does using a pencil and paper. Draw labeled boxes for the variables and nodes, and arrows for the pointers and links. Then erase and redraw arrows as you change the pointers or links.

If it doesn't make much sense yet, start drawing nodes and pointers on paper and play around with them. I assume you ask this because you are attending a datastructures class, if not just use std::list (or std::forward_list). Also adding this-> is almost never needed.

How exactly does this line here work?
headObj->InsertAfter(nodeObj1);
What is the significance of the arrow syntax? It allows access to a member function, but I don't know what that means.

It sounds like you need to get a good book.

@droid Which book are you reading? If the answer is none then now is the time to get one. C++ is not a language that you can just pick up, some proper study is required. It's clear that you have some basic concepts, (like pointers and member functions) missing or wrong.

Maybe it helps to visualise what happens throughout the execution of main:
The first statements of interest are:
headObj = new IntNode(-1);
nodeObj1 = new IntNode(555);
nodeObj2 = new IntNode(999);
nodeObj3 = new IntNode(777);

Although these statements are grouped with the respective calls of InsertAfter, it wouldn't matter if we would execute the above statements first.
Each calls the constructor of class IntNode, which will initialise the allocated structure and return a pointer to it, which is assigned to the respective variable (headObj, nodeObj,...). We can visualise the resulting state as follows:
              headObj                    nodeObj1                   nodeObj2                   nodeObj3
                 ↓                          ↓                          ↓                          ↓
┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐
│ dataVal     │ -1      │  │ dataVal     │ 555     │  │ dataVal     │ 999     │  │ dataVal     │ 777     │
├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  
│ nextNodePtr │ nullptr │  │ nextNodePtr │ nullptr │  │ nextNodePtr │ nullptr │  │ nextNodePtr │ nullptr │
└─────────────┴─────────┘  └─────────────┴─────────┘  └─────────────┴─────────┘  └─────────────┴─────────┘  

Let's follow the execution of InsertAfter step by step when headObj->InsertAfter(nodeObj1) is called: First of all, this is a method, and so this corresponds to headObj while this method executes. The (pointer) value of nodeObj1 is taken over by the nodeLoc parameter variable, and so nodeLoc will point to the second node in above diagram. A second local variable (besides nodeLoc) is defined with tmpNext = this->nextNodePtr, which is nullptr (as depicted in the first node in above diagram). After that statement we have this state:
              headObj                    nodeObj1                   nodeObj2                   nodeObj3
                 ↓                          ↓                          ↓                          ↓
┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐
│ dataVal     │ -1      │  │ dataVal     │ 555     │  │ dataVal     │ 999     │  │ dataVal     │ 777     │
├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  
│ nextNodePtr │ nullptr │  │ nextNodePtr │ nullptr │  │ nextNodePtr │ nullptr │  │ nextNodePtr │ nullptr │
└─────────────┴─────────┘  └─────────────┴─────────┘  └─────────────┴─────────┘  └─────────────┴─────────┘  
                 ↑                          ↑
               this                       nodeLoc

      tmpNext = nullptr

The next assignment is this->nextNodePtr = nodeLoc. If you follow the arrows in the above diagram, you can see this assignment will replace the nullptr value in the leftmost node:
              headObj                    nodeObj1                   nodeObj2                   nodeObj3
                 ↓                          ↓                          ↓                          ↓
┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐
│ dataVal     │ -1      │  │ dataVal     │ 555     │  │ dataVal     │ 999     │  │ dataVal     │ 777     │
├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  
│ nextNodePtr │ ──────────►│ nextNodePtr │ nullptr │  │ nextNodePtr │ nullptr │  │ nextNodePtr │ nullptr │
└─────────────┴─────────┘  └─────────────┴─────────┘  └─────────────┴─────────┘  └─────────────┴─────────┘  
                 ↑                          ↑
               this                       nodeLoc

      tmpNext = nullptr

The last statement in the function nodeLoc->nextNodePtr = tmpNext; has no effect, as tmpNext is nullptr and that is also the value of nodeLoc->nextNodePtr.
The next call of InsertAfter is nodeObj1->InsertAfter(nodeObj2), and will end like this:
              headObj                    nodeObj1                   nodeObj2                   nodeObj3
                 ↓                          ↓                          ↓                          ↓
┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐
│ dataVal     │ -1      │  │ dataVal     │ 555     │  │ dataVal     │ 999     │  │ dataVal     │ 777     │
├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  
│ nextNodePtr │ ──────────►│ nextNodePtr │ ──────────►│ nextNodePtr │ nullptr │  │ nextNodePtr │ nullptr │
└─────────────┴─────────┘  └─────────────┴─────────┘  └─────────────┴─────────┘  └─────────────┴─────────┘  
                                            ↑                          ↑
                                          this                       nodeLoc

                                 tmpNext = nullptr

And when the last call of InsertAfter is about to return:
              headObj                    nodeObj1                   nodeObj2                   nodeObj3
                 ↓                          ↓                          ↓                          ↓
┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐
│ dataVal     │ -1      │  │ dataVal     │ 555     │  │ dataVal     │ 999     │  │ dataVal     │ 777     │
├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  
│ nextNodePtr │ ──────────►│ nextNodePtr │ ──────────►│ nextNodePtr │ ──────────►│ nextNodePtr │ nullptr │
└─────────────┴─────────┘  └─────────────┴─────────┘  └─────────────┴─────────┘  └─────────────┴─────────┘  
                                                                       ↑                          ↑
                                                                     this                       nodeLoc

                                                            tmpNext = nullptr

Another scenario
In the above run it is not so evident what the role is of tmpNext. It would be more clear if we would insert a node after a node that already is linked with a successor node, and the inserted node must end up between them.
Let's say that we have the same main, except for the last call of InsertAfter. Then we have this state where the last node is not yet part of the linked list:
              headObj                    nodeObj1                   nodeObj2                   nodeObj3
                 ↓                          ↓                          ↓                          ↓
┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐
│ dataVal     │ -1      │  │ dataVal     │ 555     │  │ dataVal     │ 999     │  │ dataVal     │ 777     │
├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  
│ nextNodePtr │ ──────────►│ nextNodePtr │ ──────────►│ nextNodePtr │ nullptr │  │ nextNodePtr │ nullptr │
└─────────────┴─────────┘  └─────────────┴─────────┘  └─────────────┴─────────┘  └─────────────┴─────────┘  

Now, let's execute headObj->InsertAfter(nodeObj3), with the aim to inject nodeObj3 between the first two nodes.
This call of InsertAfter will assign to tmpNext the same pointer value as nodeObj1 has, as that is the pointer value of headObj->nextNodePtr:
              headObj                    nodeObj1                   nodeObj2                   nodeObj3
                 ↓                          ↓                          ↓                          ↓
┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐
│ dataVal     │ -1      │  │ dataVal     │ 555     │  │ dataVal     │ 999     │  │ dataVal     │ 777     │
├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  
│ nextNodePtr │ ──────────►│ nextNodePtr │ ──────────►│ nextNodePtr │ nullptr │  │ nextNodePtr │ nullptr │
└─────────────┴─────────┘  └─────────────┴─────────┘  └─────────────┴─────────┘  └─────────────┴─────────┘  
                 ↑                          ↑                                                     ↑
               this                      tmpNext                                                nodeLoc

The assignment this->nextNodePtr = nodeLoc will now rewire the first node, as its nextNodePtr is updated:
              headObj                    nodeObj1                   nodeObj2                   nodeObj3
                 ↓                          ↓                          ↓                          ↓
┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐
│ dataVal     │ -1      │  │ dataVal     │ 555     │  │ dataVal     │ 999     │  │ dataVal     │ 777     │
├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  
│ nextNodePtr │ ─────────┐ │ nextNodePtr │ ──────────►│ nextNodePtr │ nullptr │┌►│ nextNodePtr │ nullptr │
└─────────────┴─────────┘│ └─────────────┴─────────┘  └─────────────┴─────────┘│ └─────────────┴─────────┘  
                 ↑       │                  ↑                                  │                  ↑
               this      │               tmpNext                               │                nodeLoc
                         └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

And finally, the role of tmpNext becomes apparent, as it is assigned to nodeLoc->nextNodePtr:
              headObj                    nodeObj1                   nodeObj2                   nodeObj3
                 ↓                          ↓                          ↓                          ↓
┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐
│ dataVal     │ -1      │  │ dataVal     │ 555     │  │ dataVal     │ 999     │  │ dataVal     │ 777     │
├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  
│ nextNodePtr │ ─────────┐ │ nextNodePtr │ ──────────►│ nextNodePtr │ nullptr │┌►│ nextNodePtr │ ─────────┐
└─────────────┴─────────┘│ └─────────────┴─────────┘  └─────────────┴─────────┘│ └─────────────┴─────────┘│  
   ▲             ↑       │                  ↑                                  │                  ↑       │
   │           this      │               tmpNext                               │                nodeLoc   │
   │                     └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘                          │
   └──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

The node has been successfully inserted at the desired place. By just moving around blocks, we can get a cleaner view:
              headObj                    nodeObj3                   nodeObj1                   nodeObj2
                 ↓                          ↓                          ↓                          ↓
┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐  ┌─────────────┬─────────┐
│ dataVal     │ -1      │  │ dataVal     │ 777     │  │ dataVal     │ 555     │  │ dataVal     │ 999     │
├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  ├─────────────┼─────────┤  
│ nextNodePtr │ ──────────►│ nextNodePtr │ ──────────►│ nextNodePtr │ ──────────►│ nextNodePtr │ nullptr │
└─────────────┴─────────┘  └─────────────┴─────────┘  └─────────────┴─────────┘  └─────────────┴─────────┘  
                 ↑                                                     ↑                          ↑
               this                                                  tmpNext                    nodeLoc   

Note that you don't really need to write this-> explicitly in this code.
Hope this clarifies it.

how did you created those wonderful tables in markdown

Nothing special. I just have mapped those box-characters to my keyboard.

Sorry for out of the topic, if you have any reference for those on how to do could you please share the link. Its really really helpful. I literally struggle lot with table syntax in markdown

I didn't use any markdown feature for it. I just typed those characters one by one, and then used copy/paste. You can find the unicode characters at Wikipedia: box-drawing, arrows, ... To map keyboard keys to certain characters, use a tool like AutoHotKey.

A few questions. If "this->" in the InsertAfter function is supposed to be headObj, then how is nodeObj1 being assigned the value of the argument being passed into the parameter? Based on my understanding of what you're saying, headObj is pointing to whatever the result is of the function.
this->nextNodePtr, which would currently be null, is assigned the location of nodeObj1. Then the pointer going from nodeLoc to nextNodePtr is assigned tmpNext's value, which is null.

When you call a method like so: x->method(), then while that method executes, this has the same value as x. But in your main, the part before that -> is always different, so with each call of InsertAfter, you have a different this. The parameter is a whole other story, and not related to this. The values that you pass between parentheses in the method call, are assigned to the parameter variables that are defined in the function heading.

"this->nextNodePtr, which would currently be null, is assigned the location of nodeObj1. Then the pointer going from nodeLoc to nextNodePtr is assigned tmpNext's value, which is null.": I think I went in quite some detail about what happens here in my answer?

Just to say it differently: x->method() means: execute method with this equal to x. It does not mean x will point to what ever method returns (not sure if that was your misunderstanding).

referring to your question about headObj i think the next line, nodeLoc->nextNodePtr = tmpNext;, sets the nextNodePtr pointer of the new node (nodeLoc) to the next temporarily stored node (tmpNext). This step is crucial because it correctly connects the new node to the linked list without interrupting the flow of the chain. Essentially, after inserting the new node between the current node and its next one, this line restores the link between the new node and the node that was originally after the current node, ensuring that the linked list is still properly linked.

How exactly does this line here work? headObj->InsertAfter(nodeObj1); What is the significance of the arrow syntax? It allows access to a member function, but I don't know what that means.

in c++ the arrow operator is used to access a member of an object pointer. In the line headObgj -> InsertAfter(nodeObj1); headObj is a pointer to an object of type IntNode, and InsertAfter is a member function of the IntNode class. In short by using the arrow operator, you are telling the compiler to call the InsertAfter member function on the object pointed to headObj.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
